# cups: Unable to open listen socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address

Tags: debian, networking, cups

I have installed `cups` on Debian 12.
when I start it, I see following errors in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
Unable to open listen socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address
```

also, `netstat -lptn` shows port localhost:631 is not listening

When I start cups with strace:

```
strace -o cups.strace /usr/sbin/cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf -s /etc/cups/cups-files.conf
```

I see following error:

```
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 6
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(631), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)
close(6)                                = 0
write(4, "E [11/Nov/2023:07:28:53 +0100] U"..., 121) = 121
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 6
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
unlink("/run/cups/cups.sock")           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

full strace [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AADQcHvlFA)

Comment: It looks like you have no interface with the address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Bib - you are right! I did not have `lo` interface up. `ifup lo` fixed the problem